# Display icon at top of the screen - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on android UX design. I am using `RelativeLayout`. I want to do the below screen in android.

[image]

1. I want to know how to show an icon at the top of the screen (red marked).
2. When i click that icon, i want to show the information about the app with a black background.

I am new to android and i don't know how to do this. Need some help to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an ActionBar (Toolbar) Menu icon:

You need to add a menu file inside res/menu, like: main.xml formed this way:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_main"
        android:title="@string/action_main"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Over "android:icon" goes the one you want, "android:title" the one you want when the user long press the icon.

**EDIT** Check the updated code with comments

To have listener (onClick actions) do this over the Activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.action_main){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Main action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Toast only have a small duration to show something,
            // even when you long press the item, the Title is also a
            // Toast. You can literally do anything here. Show stuffs,
            // hide it, open activities, close the app, etc

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: I tried the way you guided. ic_launcher icon is not shown. When i click the three dots at left side, i can see the Settings menu and on clicking the settings menu, it is showing as "Main action is selected!". I want to show the ic_launcher icon near by the three dots. Can you guide me how to do this.

Comment: Do you have other items inside the menu file? You must change android:orderInCategory="100" to set the order.  Also, use android:showAsAction="always" to always see the icon. In my example, the icon only shows if you have "room" to show it (probably small screen or title too long)

Comment: I have only one item inside menu file. android:orderInCategory and android:showAsAction is same as you said. Event then the Icon is not shown. The title is of 10 character. Please advise.

Comment: Are you calling the correct menu inflate? Like: getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); BTW: Which device SDK are you testing? You're using Actionbar? Toolbar? Which "extends" you're using?

Comment: I am calling this inflate getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); I am not using Actionbar or Toolbar. I created the layout and changed the main.xml under menu as you suggested. Do i need to use Actionbar. where to add the Actionbar.

Comment: Yes... that the best way to use action menus. Actionbar/Toolbar are really simple to use and get that icon you need.

Comment: Issue is with image size. I re sized the image and worked for me.

Comment: I want to show the contents on clicking the icon. Now the example you given is just shows the text and disappear. I want to show the text on clicking the icon and again on clicking i need to hide the text. Can you send me a sample or the way how to achieve.

Comment: Check the updated answer. The titles are also Toast, that's why it disappears. Try to use a small layout to show there or a menu, wherever you want. It's just a listener, so, it works as a OnClickListener for a button, imagen, etc

Answer (score 1):

```
add in menul
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:title="@string/phone"
    android:icon="@drawable/phone"
    android:showAsAction="always"
/>
</menu

After that in java
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.phone:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }
    return true;
```

Comment: I tried the way you guided. Phone icon is not shown. When i click the three dots at left side, i can see the Settings menu and on clicking the settings menu, it is showing as "You selected Phone". I want to show the Phone icon near by the three dots. Can you guide me how to do this.

Comment: Issue is with image size. I re sized the image and worked for me.